# image gallery or image carousel in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

i am trying to make a very simple image gallery/carousel but im having problems with the code im working on right now..i tried searching in google for the proper term used for the carousel i want but i was not able to find one..this is the image sample of the carousel i want to achieve[image]
i want the images to loop endless and i want umlimited images in the carousel as long as there are images in the folder it will show in the carousel

Comment: You can try flexslider thats simple and easy and then you can effects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of building one from scratch why not uses one pre built, I have used theses guys before and they are great, best thing it's fully responsive.
http://bxslider.com

Just follow the easy steps they give you.

This example here http://bxslider.com/examples/ticker can be customised to look exactly like what your after, if you need help customising it once you have it working let me know.

Comment: i think i need to download thing for it right?

Comment: No if you use the URL link in CSS there is no need to download the jQuery library

Comment: sir the link is showing internal error..is there a need to licensing here sir?i just dont want to get into trouble

Comment: No there is not, I've used it many times. What error are you getting and have you called the function in php ?

Comment: no the link  http://bxslider.com/examples/tickercan when i click it im i dont go to the page

Comment: Ahh the example, ok sorry about that put in wrong link, here you are http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-dynamic-number-slides

Comment: No problem at all. Once you have the slider up and running if you need help with the CSS let me know.

Comment: ok sir i will ask another question if i encounter a problem

Comment: Ok @saltine Kianne I hope it works out for you.