# image gallery make the first image big

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

i made a carousel iamge from [this](http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/making-an-infinite-jquery-carousel/) tutorial and i want the first image to be big and when i click next next the next image will show on the big div as well as when the image is click the image will show in the big div i have tried something like this

```
$("bigimage_container").ready(function() {
            document.getElementById("bigimage_container").style.background = 'url('+  +') ';
            document.getElementById("bigimage_container").style.backgroundPosition = "center center";
            document.getElementById("bigimage_container").style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
            document.getElementById("bigimage_container").style.backgroundSize = "100% 100%";
        });
```

but my problem is how to get the url or the first image then i came up with this

```
$('#carousel_ul li:first').each(function() {
        alert($(this).attr('src'))
        });
```

but when the alert show it says undefined..any help is appreciated explain on how to make this or a tutorial will be great..if you know how to make a gallery like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24953846/image-gallery-or-image-carousel-in-jquery/24954023?noredirect=1#comment38784308_24954023) it will be wonderful..making a image gallery like in apple store is really cool..

**Update:
html**

```
<div id="bigimage_container"></div>
        <div id='carousel_container'>
          <div id='left_scroll'><img src='left.png' /></div>
            <div id='carousel_inner'>
                <ul id='carousel_ul'>
                    <li><a href='#'><img src='1.png' /></a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'><img src='2.png' /></a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'><img src='3.png' /></a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'><img src='4.png' /></a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'><img src='5.png' /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
          <div id='right_scroll'><img src='right.png' /></div>
          </div>
```

Comment: and li dont't have a src attribute

Comment: ow i didnt know about that  wait i will edit the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("bigimage_container").style.background = 'url('+$('#carousel_ul li:first img').attr("src") +') ';
            document.getElementById("bigimage_container").style.backgroundPosition = "center center";
            document.getElementById("bigimage_container").style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
            document.getElementById("bigimage_container").style.backgroundSize = "100% 100%";
```

based on the answer of sir Ehsan Sajjad..it worked for me

Comment: i will upvote my answer because i posted it before you did your edit thank you for the idea @EhsanSajjad

Answer (score 1):

**img** tag is inside li so you have to get it this way:

```
 alert($('#carousel_ul li:first img').attr("src"));
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/SqKfH/)

you can set it on div this way:

```
$("#bigimage_container").css("background-image","url('"+$('#carousel_ul li:first img').attr("src")+"')")
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/SqKfH/1/)

Comment: the alert works but how will i make it a background or make it big in div that is the main question sir..i tried putting it in `document.getElementById("bigimage_container").style.background = 'url('+  +') ';` but it does not work

Comment: that is a very broad thing you asking

Comment: on making the image a background of the div?

Comment: in question you are asking how to make gallery

Comment: no i made the gallery already sir what i am trying is to make the first image of the gallery big like a background of a big  div above the gallery...